# LinkedList addSort method with Scanner

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

So I have an "ItemList" where every node contains a name and a number and I want to make an addSort method that adds in the list in alphabetical order.

I already have two methods:

one where I find the index where it should be:

```
public int getIndexName(String id){
    Node temp = header;
    int count = 0;
    while(temp.next.itm.name.compareTo(id) < 0){
        temp = temp.next;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

and one that adds with an index:

```
public void add( Item newItem, int index)
  {
      if(index < 0 || index > size){
          throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      }
    Node nynode = new Node(newItem);
    Node temp = header;
    //go to the index or the last element in list, whichever comes first.
    for(int i = 0; i< index && temp.next != null; i++){
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    // set the nynode's next-node reference to this node's next-node reference
    nynode.setNext(temp.next);
    //set this node's next-node reference to the new node
    temp.setNext(nynode);
    size++;

  }
```

and now Im working on my addSort method which looks like this:

```
public void addSort(Item newItem){
    if(size > 2){
        int index = this.getIndexName(newItem.name);
        this.add(newItem, index);
    }
    else{
        add(newItem);
    }
}
```

and if size isnt bigger than 2 it just adds with a normal add method because I need two names to compare with. This works with like 4 elements and it gets sorted but with more elements I get a nullpointerexception. And with im gonna do it with a Scanner with alot more elements so I need help with what Im doing wrong.

thanks in advance!